# Removal of JS:Miner-AI[PUP]

Tags: windows-7, malware, virus, trojan

When I try to access every site without using HTTPS. I get a popup from avast telling me they have blocked it.

It says 'JS:Miner-AI[PUP]'. When I try to access google.com (without https) it happens as well.

I have tried the following:

Scan with Avast, adaware and Malwarebytes (used to remove previous versions of js:miner)

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can do to remove it?

[image: Avast popup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the router was infected. Once the router was replaced the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is going on but I am sure google.com is not malicious so my best guess is that your computer is infected with malware which tries to inject Javascript/HTML code into every page you visit probably by hooking wininet functions.

Most Malwares inject code into chrome, firefox and internet explorer. one way to check is to install another web browser and check if everything is good in that browser or not. Another way is to restart the computer and run again in safe mode (disable all the start up programs except for AV) and again run your favorite browser to see if the problem solved. if the browser's exe file (chrome.exe or firefox.exe) or any of the their DLLs are infected, then you have to reinstall the browser.

hope it helps :-)

Comment: Yes, that was my point. As long as the traffic isn't encrypted it causes avast to popup with that message. Well, I did try to start windows in safe mode, and the problem wasn't there. The issue I have is that it happens even tho I don't run a webbrowser (ie, when a program tries to update it self using http it happens). I will try to delete all the browser, and check if that helps.

Comment: I deleted all the browsers, and downloaded firefox on another computer and installed it, and the problem remains..